# iOS: My console doesn't show any printed statement and any log

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

Now I use the latest X code.   Whenever I use `print()` and `NSLog` method to see any variables, the console doesn't show anything.  I set some breakpoints and I made sure of execution of the print lines. However, any print statements didn't give any output.   Why? Do you have any idea of what makes my console silent?  Any comments should be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

This is my console within Xcode. It shows nothing and doesn't react with any print statements.
[image]

Comment: which version of xcode you are using??

Comment: Please make sure, You are selecting All Output ...

Comment: Please relaunch Xcode and check All output selected in the console.

Comment: My xcode version is 8.3.2.  And output is nothing.  I can't see any output in the console. And relaunch and clean have no effect with this problem.

Comment: Are you talking about the console in Xcode? Or the separate Console app? Assuming you're talking about within Xcode, can you answer Bala's question? Which option is chosen at the bottom of the console panel? "All output", "Debugger output" or "Target output"?

Comment: Of course, "All output"

Answer (score 2):

make sure you selected "All Output" and also the console been showed, see the image

[XCode debug area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0DcN.png)